# Python. Решить задачу. Спасибо заранее

Tags: python

```
def end_zeros_or_numbers(num: int) -> int:
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(end_zeros(0))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert end_zeros(0) == 1
    assert end_zeros(1) == 0
    assert end_zeros(10) == 1
    assert end_zeros(101) == 0
    assert end_zeros(245) == 0
    assert end_zeros(100100) == 2
    print("Coding complete? Click 'Check' to earn cool rewards!")
```

Я пробую сам решить задачу, но эту я не понял, КАК решать.. Я читал статьи на хабре как правильно решать. Я объяснил мысленно, мысленно созданному мною субъекту. И как бы я понял суть задачи. Вот задача.
На функцию подаются числа переменной длины. Необходимо написать функцию, которая напишет, сколько нулей встречается в числе, НО, функция должна вывести эти числа, при условии, что они следуют друг за другом подряд, если такого числа нет, то просто вывести, сколько нулей в числе.
Например: 1000000, функция должна вывести, что в числе 6 нулей.
Другой пример: 10979000000, фунеция должна вывести, что в числе 6 нулей, так как они идут подряд.
Примечания: Если существует число, к примеру: 10009000000, то вывод должен быть тоже шесть нулей, так как этих нулей больше чем в [10009]. Также данная функция может выводить и другие числа, которые идут подряд друг за другом. Использование регулярных выражений запрещается. **Ребят, я знаю, что многим просто будет лень это делать, вы можете не писать код, просто напишите словами. Спасибо заранее.**

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста что вы пробовали.

Comment: @S.Nick https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1175808/revisions

Comment: То что я пробовал, выглядет бредово. Я просто написал цикл for прошелся по входным числам, написал count, если встречает одинаковое число. Но я не знаю как подряд сделать.

Comment: ваше условие противоречит строке ```assert end_zeros(101) == 0```

Comment: Oops, забыл дописать. Просто за основу задачи взяли другую задачу. А это дополненная.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте `itertools.groupby`. Им удобно группировать подряд идущие символы.

Пример:

```
import itertools


def end_zeros(num: int) -> int:
    size = 0

    for x, items in itertools.groupby(str(num)):
        if x == '0':
            size = max(size, len(list(items)))

    return size


if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert end_zeros(10979000000) == 6
    assert end_zeros(1000000) == 6
    assert end_zeros(10009) == 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> translate_table = dict(zip_longest(map(str, range(1, 10)), ",", fillvalue=","))
>>> num = "100100012300"
>>> print(len(max(num.translate(str.maketrans(translate_table)).split(","))))
... 3
>>> num = "100100"
>>> print(len(max(num.translate(str.maketrans(translate_table)).split(","))))
... 2
```